# How can I sort elements of list in function?

Tags: python, list, function, sorting

Why I got:    None
None

```
def odd_even(*number):
    even = []
    odd = []
    for i in number:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even.append(i)
        else:
            odd.append(i)
    print(even.sort())
    print(odd.sort())
```

```
odd_even(1,5,7,8,4,3,26,59,48,7,5,45)
```

I just tried sorting elements of list
But result is

```
None
None
```

Comment: As a very general rule, utility functions like this should not print their results.  They should RETURN their results, and let the caller decide what to do with it.  That's how you achieve code reuse.  If you had done `return even, odd`, you would have seen that this actually worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, `list.sort` has the effect of sorting the existing list. As such, in keeping with Python conventions, it does not return the list, but rather `None`.

This is why you're seeing what you are. You can either use `list.sort` in a separate step before printing them, or use `sorted`. E.g. `print(sorted(even))`.

You might also sort the original list *before* separating into evens and odds. Doing this will ensure both resulting lists are sorted. However, this is likely to be less performant as sorting two smaller lists is less costly than sorting one larger list.

Comment: Now, THERE'S a question that could open debate!  Is it quicker to sort one list of 12 items, or two lists of 6 items?  Unless the sort is `O(N)`, it would be better to do them separately, but it's an interesting thought experiment.

Comment: It also depends on the distribution of odd and even numbers in the original list.

Comment: @TimRoberts Small puzzle: For a shuffled list `list(range(10**6))`, the solution sorting beforehand is *faster*, ~600 ms vs ~700 ms for the solution with two sorts afterwards:

Comment: [Benchmark](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=tVNLbtswEF10x1PMpghpqEbsFEEhQCcxDEGJZhqiJiWQowCBkXUP0U027b5XyDF6mvIjWnayK1DuZuZx5r3h449f4xM_DPbl5efE9OnLnw_ftRkHx-A62w9GkBsMsDaoGeZKjipwOGLHGeG5Y-1Z3_uCMtjZKuR7fBSiR4Kh71t8RCtXdjJ36FQtIJyYggZ2-xQF0BLQ4ECDtpAvZHw8mkL-I2yhaeB6SZd2624c0fZSq1MJDx4vgWHSG1y66gN3qQqX89AhT84mVBVrl6q2_yArNsdeXtz7f_Le86fJhvdqThqqRY0QmVWoHsK7yuCGryg316vVrVIie2PtHyaiAxYBQkRnxIZHqoPYJJSi0DToOe0rGsVLmtVyRO8YVrDBm4Tns8Wkdjvaq119s9-fi6CrY_SXZK_q2_WWnuH1NxyT2VLuc8oZD1dBZejaxq5Fwzz7kt2yPQ6UssXloTN3fVcDnR63mr3YbJblF5pl36zyUDqTkmZU8A2fmrSBmcPotGVZdlIBrdvWdgbbVuX_OH_L8j3_Ag)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `sorted()` function which returns a new sorted list and leaves the original list unaffected:

```py
def odd_even(*number):
    even = []
    odd = []
    for i in number:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even.append(i)
        else:
            odd.append(i)
    print(sorted(even))
    print(sorted(odd))

odd_even(1,5,7,8,4,3,26,59,48,7,5,45)
#output
#[4, 8, 26, 48]
#[1, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 45, 59]
```

Other Method (Fix your solution):

If you want to print the sorted lists, you should sort the lists first and then print them:

```py
def odd_even(*number):
    even = []
    odd = []
    for i in number:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even.append(i)
        else:
            odd.append(i)
    even.sort()
    odd.sort()
    print(even)
    print(odd)

odd_even(1,5,7,8,4,3,26,59,48,7,5,45)
```

Other Methode:

In this code, we use a list comprehension to filter out even and odd numbers from `number` and sort them directly as they are created. Then we print the `even` and `odd` lists which are already sorted.

```py
def odd_even(*number):
    even = sorted([i for i in number if i % 2 == 0])
    odd = sorted([i for i in number if i % 2 != 0])
    print(even)
    print(odd)
odd_even(1,5,7,8,4,3,26,59,48,7,5,45)
```

Comment: The list comprehensions look nice, but it does mean making two passes over the original list, vs. one. You might also use the `partition` function in [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/).